# What is the difference between a regular array, and array of pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

Can someone plz explain me what is the diffrence between those tow lines
and when we will want to use each one of then

```
int array[] = { 1, 2, 3 }; // init a regular array


int *numList = {1, 2, 3}; //  init an array of pointers?
```

I am expecting that there are probably seenarios we will want to use  the second over the first,
But when?

Thank You in Advance

Comment: `int *numList = {1, 2, 3}` is `int *numList = 1;`. The extra values are discarded.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `int *numList = (int[3]){1, 2, 3};`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're conflating some concepts. As [@ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) noted, your second line:

```c
int *numList = {1, 2, 3};
```

Gets treated as:

```c
int *numList = 1;
```

Which not an array, nor a valid pointer.
If you want to create an array of pointers, you use the same syntax as normal arrays, with the type being a pointer:

```c
int* numList[] = {
    &array[0],
    &array[1],
    &array[2]
};
```

Will create an array of 3 int pointers, pointing to your original array's elements.